# How to complete the constructor if a class member comes from another class?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

For example, I have two classes Array and Stack.

```
template <typename T>
class Array {
private:
T* array;
int size;
...
public:
Array(int size);
...
}

template <typename T>
class Stack {
private:
int top;
Array<T> stack;
...
public:
Stack(int size);
...
}
```

Basically I'm implementing Stack class using Array class.
How to define stack member variable (Array< T >) in Stack constructor?

Comment: Do you know about *constructor initialize lists*? If not, then start with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Stack::Stack(size_t size) : stack (size) {}
```

Also, don't use int for container sizes or iterators; use size_t unless there is a specific reason not to.